# Merging two files into third file gives gibberish

Tags: c, do-while, file-handling

Actually I am trying to merge two files into a third file using a `do-while` loop. The program runs fine but when I open the third file, it only contains gibberish.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    FILE *f2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
    FILE *f3 = fopen("file3.txt", "w");

    if (f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL || f3 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Issue with the files\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    char let;
    printf("File-1\n");

    do
    {
        fputc(let, f3);
        printf("%c", let);
    } while ((let = fgetc(f1)) != EOF);

    printf("\n\nFile-2\n");

    do
    {
        fputc(let, f3);
        printf("%c", let);
    } while ((let = fgetc(f2)) != EOF);
    
    printf("\nTASK COMPLETED!! Files have been merged");

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
}
```

File 3- giving gibberish:

[image]

But when I use `while` instead of `do-while` the things work well and third file gives the desired result. I don't know why `do-while` is creating issue.

The content of File - 1:

```
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

The content of File - 2:

```
Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
```

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**. This is actually rather important for that `EOF  comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using do-while loop was mistake. But still if you want to use it then do following changes.

1. Change `char let` to `char let='\0'` .
2. After first while loop re-assign `let='\0'` to clear buffer.
3. While merging 2 or more files, open destination file in append mode to avoid overwriting. `FILE *f3 = fopen("file3.txt","a");`

Comment: Or for short: `char let = 0;`